# Custom errors defaultRedirect not found

Tags: asp.net, custom-errors

I am trying to use

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="error.html" mode="RemoteOnly" />
```

It looks like the `error.html` is not being found and instead the server displays default

> Server Error in '/' Application page

.

I have a problem with assemblies on my live site ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231147/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-codeanalysis-csharp-the-module-was) ) and not sure something is wrong with my custom error settings (unlikely) or it's not working because my site doesn't compile?

Comment: How are you accessing the site? From the same machine the server is running on?

Comment: @mason no, through web address, it's a hosted site

Comment: Refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140674/iis-custom-errors-not-showing-custom-error-page, from other system you can set <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>

Comment: @Anil Setting it to On shouldn't be necessary. RemoteOnly should be sufficient in this case.

Comment: Can you show that configuration line's context? What elements do you have it nested under? Which file did you place it in? Did you verify that the files that end up getting deployed to the server are exactly what you'd expect?

Comment: @mason As you can see I have no element underneath customerrors. But even when I had there was no difference - the defaultRedirect value was ignored

Comment: I'm not asking about elements under it. I'm asking about what's above it. We need to verify that 1) your element is nested in the right place and 2) this configuration is in the right file. When you're trying to debug things, you need to verify every part in the pipeline in order to identify what's wrong. Incidentally, what is the rest of the error message that you're seeing on the Yellow Screen of Death?